# Windows client unable to connect Unix server (VMware)

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, client-server

I 'm working on a simple Windows client (Windows 7) - Unix server (Fedora 19 - VMware) application. However, connection fails with error 10060. The code seems to work fine. I think there is a problem with the settings of VMware Workstation 10. Any help would be appreciated.

Specifically: VMnet8: Type: NAT, External Connection: NAT, Host Connection: Connected, DHCP: Enabled.

P.S. The Firewall is turned off.

Comment: What application are you using to connect? What is running on the server? (Windows and Fedora are not valid answers. HTTP would be a good answer, Apache even better)

Comment: Client is a console application (C++) running via Visual Studio 2012 and server is a C program running via Terminal. Both processes use TCP protocol. Client prompts the user to enter data in order to send them.

Comment: what port does your C program run on, and did you create a port forwarding rule in vmwares nat to provide remote hosts access to it? if not, either create one, or switch your network type to bridged.

Comment: I created a port forwarding rule in VMnet8: Host port: 27015, Type: TCP, Virtual machine IP address: 192.168.32.130, Virtual machine port: 27015, but still get the same error. I tried switch my network type to bridged but get the error:  Cannot change network to bridged: There are no un-bridged host network adapters.  Except VMnet8, there is VMnet1, which is Host-only.

Comment: Have you consulted the documentation for whatever TCP library you are using to determine what 10060 means?

Comment: 10060: "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time." The error explanation doesn't identify the problem.

Comment: Have you reviewed the logs on your server? Have you captured packets during a connection attempt? See if the server is receiving the request, acknowledging the request, etc. Also, what is making you think VMWare is the problem?